# Some of the system keyboard strokes do not work on Teamviewer 8?

Tags: 13.10, teamviewer

When I connect to a remote machine, Enter, Shift and some other strokes do not work. Right click of the mouse doesn't work either. However letter keys are perfectly fine. Do you have any reasoning?

Comment: Are you running the [newest version](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux.aspx) for Ubuntu?

Comment: Not off-topic if he's running the Ubuntu deb package.